# Does a patch cabinet require both a front and a back access door?

Tags: networking, patch-panel

In my company (university), we have very old 19’’ cabinets 80x80x220 cm that are taking quite some space in a student lab. The cabinet is less than half full with switches and patch panels.

I proposed to buy a smaller cabinet, half the height and perhaps less deep. We could fix the cabinet against a wall and then gain previous space. We checked that we have enough length on the cables.

The technician I’m charge of cable management said that this change would be totally impossible because this kind of patch cabinet require a front and a back access. This is not my domain of expertise and I would like to clarify this point.

For normal use, does a patch cabinet composed of switches and patch panels require a front and a back access meaning this kind of cabinets cannot be attached agains a wall?

Comment: It depends on the equipment going into the rack. A switch with ports on one side and AC , power switch and reset on the other side could be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

No, most patch panels Ive seen/used are fixed to the wall and only have access from the front. They generally have a row/multiple rows of RJ45 jacks which have the wires terminating behind the faceplate, and all the jumpering is done in the front.  Handling power/ups can be a nit tricky, but is entirely doable.  If you have stuff which generates heat you need to consider this and possibly have fans pushing air upwards.

If the cabinets are not very full/heavy a compromise might be to get swinging cabinets - ie cabonets hinged to the wall but can be swivelled to provide access to the rear. They are fairly common - do a google search for "19" cabinet hinged back"